# Tree-view: Search

Tags: search, tree

I'm projecting a New tree-view for a system, but my doubt is about the Search.

Would I put a button that the user select if he wants to search also subfolders, or the system would to search automatically in your subfolders ?

---

Sketch of interface, for more details

[image]

Comment: And to put others buttons , like: "include subfolders" ; "include all folders".

Comment: Did you get answer for your Q

Comment: @grafixguru not yet.

Answer (score 2):

1.If the tree nodes are fixed, not going to increase and its around 100 nodes. Then better to go with just search box ( no need of button).It searches automatically as soon as user types 3 character.

[image]

2. If the tree node is gong to increase in future, nodes are around 1000+ then its better to add a button with search box. User will input the search criteria in a search text box  and trigger search functionality with 'Go' button. This is the scalable. 
   [image]

Comment: Hi. The search box is about that content has in the each folder, and no about the folders specifically.

Comment: note getting your comment, could you please rephrase the sentence.

Comment: The search field to which I refer, it is search for content within folders, not the search for folders in the tree-view.

Comment: Ok got it. Please update the question with details. If you could share the simple sketch, it helps to give better solution/answer. Based on my understanding  it's better to use sear box with button. It's scalable. It helps in  the implementation n interaction. It will be clear to the user on what action they are performing.  My answer would help partially.

Comment: Updated ;) Sorry about the language in portuguese. :)

Answer (score 1):

I guess it depends on your data and the tasks your users have to perform. Without knowing more about your product, I would reccomend searching automatically in subfolders. Search is very seldom done right and from my experience, users resort to search when they cannot visually find the data they are looking for (either because there is too much data on the screen or the information hierarchy is not clear).